# "catch" errors in Android Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webkit, try-catch

I am trying to check what DOM menthods does Android Webkit Javascript support (implementing a Hybrid application) and for this purpose i implemented the following try catch method

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){try{document.body.style.backgroundColo = 'blue';}catch(err) {alert('There is an error');}})()");
```

it does not appear to catch the error (backgroundColo, as i dont get a alert message displayed. I am using a Galaxy S running Android Froyo.

tried to replace the "errr" with "ee", saw that format on a googlegroups discussion.

I have scoured the net but no indication of what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried putting the try{} around the whole line including the webView?

Comment: Are you sure that `document.body.style.backgroundColo = 'blue';` will throw an exception?

Comment: That code really makes no sense. What method are you trying to check; "loadUrl()"?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! no wonder i was getting stumped. Is there any way i can figure out what DOM methods are supported by my Samsung Galaxy S WebKit browser? document.body.style.backgroundColor does not have any effect in my Samsung Galaxy-S Webkit browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColo = 'blue';
```

is not a JS error and does not throw an exception.  You are creating a property called `backgroundColo` on the `document.body.style` object and giving it a value of `'blue'`.  I won't do anything to affect the style, but it doesn't cause a JS exception.  You can see it work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gwBVv/

Comment: Thanks for the replies!

no wonder i was getting stumped. Is there any way i can figure out what DOM methods are supported by my Samsung Galaxy S WebKit browser?

document.body.style.backgroundColor does not have any effect in my Samsung Galaxy-S Webkit browser.